# Highlight changed cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet that has numeric values saved from `C2:R22`. Once a week I run a SQL script that parses data from my databases and I copy and paste those values into the Google Sheet covering the range `C2:R22`. Each week different cells will have updated values, but the majority of the cells remain the same value from the previous week.

***Question:***

Is it possible for JavaScript to look for those changes from the previous week and highlight each cell that has changed with a color such as yellow?

Comment: Please share a dummy spreadsheet file for reproduction purposes. Kindly refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Run first one to clear highlights and save refence data

```
function saveReferenceData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sObj = { ref: "Sheet0", data: "Sheet1" };//you can change the reference and data sheet names here
  const rsh = ss.getSheetByName(sObj["ref"]);//reference sheet
  const dsh = ss.getSheetByName(sObj["data"]);//data sheet
  const dvs = dsh.getRange("C2:R22").getValues();
  dsh.getRange("C2:R22").setBackground("#ffffff");//clear highlights
  rsh.getRange(2, 3, dvs.length, dvs[0].length).setValues(dvs);

}
```

Run the second on to compare data to reference and highlight the differences

```
function highLiteChangedCells() {
  const hl = "#ffff00";
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sObj = { ref: "Sheet0", data: "Sheet1" };
  const rsh = ss.getSheetByName(sObj["ref"]);
  const rvs = rsh.getRange("C2:R22").getValues();
  const dsh = ss.getSheetByName(sObj["data"]);
  const dvs = dsh.getRange("C2:R22").getValues();;
  dvs.forEach((r,i) => {
    r.forEach((c,j) =>{
      if(c != rvs[i][j]) {
        dsh.getRange(i + 2,j + 3).setBackground(hl);//set background for non matches
      }
    });
  });
}
```